# I don't see any fields in mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I created simple migration class using the terminal "CreateUsers"

```
        class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
         def up
       create_table :users do |t|
        t.column "first_name", :string, :limit => 25
        t.string "last_name",  :limit => 25
        t.string "email", :default => "" :null => false
        t.string "password",  :limit => 40  
    t.timestamps
     end
end

def down
    drop_table :users
end
end
```

I saved and ran that on terminal using

```
rake db:migrate
```

after that I longed in into mysql account. and when I show my users fields, I only see ID and timestamps fields!!

I am wondering why I am not be able to see first name, last name, emails and password fields?

thanks

Comment: From the command line, enter the db console (`rails dbconsole`) and then type `PRAGMA table_info(users);`.  What does it say?

Comment: @JTG ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PRAGMA table_info(users)' at line 1

Comment: I fixed the code. I was missing a comma  `t.string "email", :default => "" :null => false` after that I ran on the terminal `rake db:migrate:redo`